# Texture自体の上下を反転させたい

Tags: ios, xcode, unity2d

Unityで開発しております。
WebCamTextureを使用し、端末カメラのTextureをキャプチャーして
動画を作成しております。
しかし、WebCamTextureで撮影した映像が上下反転しています。
表示の上下を反転させるならスケールや回転を使用すれば上下反転できますが、
キャプチャーした映像は上下逆のままです。

以下の方法ではGameObjectが回転するだけで、Textureが回転しているわけではないので
キャプチャした「_cameraScreen.texture」は上下反転したままでした。

```
//canvas中のrawImage
[SerializeField] private RawImage   _cameraScreen = null;
// webカメラ表示テクスチャ
private WebCamTexture   _webCam = null;

// Image rotationの初期値
private Vector3 _rotationVector = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

// 画像自体の向き
private Rect _defaultRect = new Rect(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);
private Rect _flipedRect = new Rect(0f, 1f, 1f, -1f);

// RawImageのテクスチャにWebCamTextureのインスタンスを設定
_cameraScreen.texture = _webCam;

// 表示するRawImageを回転させる
Vector3 l_angles = _cameraScreen.GetComponent<RectTransform>().eulerAngles;
l_angles.z = -_webCam.videoRotationAngle;
_cameraScreen.GetComponent<RectTransform>().eulerAngles = l_angles;

// 映像のz軸を反転させる（逆さまにする）
_rotationVector.z = -_webCam.videoRotationAngle;
_cameraScreen.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = _rotationVector;

// 上下反転してしまっている画像はもとに戻す
_cameraScreen.uvRect = _webCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? _flipedRect : _defaultRect;
```

そのためTexture自体の上下を反転させたいのですが、
方法を教えてください。

環境
Unity2020.3.1f1
iPad(第7世代)
OS16.3

以下にも同じ投稿をしております。
https://teratail.com/questions/3qpqocucwoyhlx

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/3qpqocucwoyhlx) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)